Error When Merging Two Tables Using Multiple Keys
I manage a Google BigQuery table containing records of users' phone numbers, name, physical addresses, and account numbers. For example, a record might have a phone number of 222-2222, name Foo Bar, physical address 1 Main Street, and account number 111.
Every day, I receive a new table containing similar information for both existing and new users. Here's how I handle the data:
Duplicate Check: If the new table includes a record with the same phone number and name as an existing record in my table, I skip inserting that record.
Alternative Name Handling: If the new table includes a record with the same phone number but a different name than an existing record: I log the new name as an alternative under the existing phone number along with all the other personal info that are not already in the record
Alternative Phone Number Handling: same as name handling but vice versa. If the new table includes a record with the same name but a different phone number than an existing record, I log the new phone number as an alternative under the existing name along with all the other personal info that are not already in the record
In summary, I use the phone number OR name as the lookup key. If a record with both the same phone number and name already exists, I consider it a duplicate and take no further action. Otherwise, I insert the new phone number or name along with any other data points, ensuring to log alternates where applicable.
Table A 

| account_id | phone_number | name         | address  |
| --------   | --------     | --------     | -------- |
| 111        | 222-2222     | joe smith    | 1 Main St|  

Table B 

| account_id | phone_number | name            | address   |
| --------   | --------     | --------        | --------  |
| 111        | 111-1111     | joe smith       | 2 Gold St | 
| 555        | 222-2222     | mike will       | 2 Gold St |  
| 111        | 222-2222     | sarah test      | 1 Park St | 
| 111        | 222-2222     | joe smith       | 5 John St | 
| 333        | 555-5555     | suzy suzy       | 10 Arch St| 

Desired Output:



account_id
phone_number
name
address




111;555
222-2222;111-1111
joe smith; mike will; sarah test
2 Gold St; 1 Park St


333
555-555
suzy suzy
10 Arch St



I tried the following SQL:
MERGE INTO `Table A` eu
USING `Table B` nu
ON eu.phone_number = nu.phone_number OR eu.name = nu.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (account_id, phone_number, name, address)
  VALUES (nu.account_id, nu.phone_number, nu.name, nu.address)
WHEN MATCHED AND eu.phone_number = nu.phone_number AND eu.name != nu.name THEN
  UPDATE SET name = CONCAT(eu.name,';',nu.name)
WHEN MATCHED AND eu.name = nu.name AND eu.phone_number != nu.phone_number THEN
  UPDATE SET phone_number = CONCAT(eu.phone_number,';',nu.phone_number)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    address = IF(lower(eu.address) NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',lower(nu.address),'%'), CONCAT(eu.address, ';', nu.address), eu.address),
    account_id = IF(lower(eu.account_id) NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',lower(nu.account_id),'%'), CONCAT(eu.account_id, ';', nu.account_id), eu.account_id);

But I get this error:
UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row
Thank you in advance for your help!
